# Animación de despliegue con hover y after combinados en CSS

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo un botón creado con HTML y CSS que muestra texto al pasar el cursor sobre él. Lo que quiero lograr es que haya una animación de transición, ya que no he podido hacerla.

En el código HTML, el botón se trabaja con la etiqueta de enlace "a".

Espero que puedan recrear los códigos. Les dejo un enlace a una web para que puedan consultarlo en su totalidad: https://policies.esims.one/terms (el botón es el primero en aparece en la página).

```css
.back-button{
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 0px;box-shadow: none;padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
color: #181818;
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
.back-button::before{
margin-right:10px;
background-image:url(https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/d7bb4928-a156-4682-9677-d0d5b47c3a21.png);
background-size:40px 40px;
display:inline-block;
width:40px;
height:40px;
border-radius:50%;
content:""
}
.back-button:hover:after{
content:"Home"
}
.mcnButton{
transition:.4s;
border-radius:50px!important;
box-shadow:#999 0 0 20px 0!important;outline:none;
user-select:none
}
.mcnButton:focus{
background:#eceff9!important;
color:#181818!important
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
<a class="back-button mcnButton" href="https://www.example.com/" target="_self">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar las animaciones de **CSS**. Lo que hice es poner el texto que quieres que aparezca dentro de un `<span>` y a este darle un `position: asolute` para que no ocupe espacio y así no provocar que se agrande la estructura del "botón" y también un `opacity; 0` para que en un principio sea invisible.

Con las animaciones lo único que hago es agrandar un poco el "botón" además de hacer que aparezca poco a poco el texto.

```css
.back-button {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0px;box-shadow: none;padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
  color: #181818;
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative; /* Para que sirva de limitador para el <span> en absolute */
}

.back-button span {
  position: absolute; /* Para que no ocupe espacio y así evitar que el botón se agrande */
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0; /* Inicialmente lo queremos invisible */
}

/* Cuando el ratón pase por encima del botón lanzamos la animación para que se agrande un poco */
.back-button:hover {
  animation-name: agrandar;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Cuando el ratón pase por encima del botón lanzamos la animación para que el span aparezca */
.back-button:hover span {
  animation-name: aparecer;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.back-button::before {
  margin-right:10px;
  background-image:url(https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/d7bb4928-a156-4682-9677-d0d5b47c3a21.png);
  background-size:40px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:50%;
  content:""
}

.mcnButton {
  transition:.4s;
  border-radius:50px!important;
  box-shadow:#999 0 0 20px 0!important;outline:none;
  user-select:none
}

.mcnButton:focus {
  background:#eceff9!important;
  color:#181818!important
}

/* Animación de aparecer */
@keyframes aparecer {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Animación de agrandar */
@keyframes agrandar {
  from { padding-right: 30px; }
  to { padding-right: 50px; }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
<a class="back-button mcnButton" href="https://www.example.com/" target="_self">
<span>Home</span>
</a>
</div>
```